# JSON to dynamic - 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic, asp.net-web-api

I am using MVC WebAPI and passing in JSON object to a method that has parameter defined as dynamic. When using the method I am accessing the property of the dynamic object. It throws me  this error - 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition'

```
private dynamic Method1([FromBody]dynamic obj)
{
  if (obj.Name.Value == "Hello")
  {
   //Code
  }
}
```

JSON has right Key-Value pair.

This code works fine on other machine but throws error on one. Just wondering if there is something wrong with my installation or I am missing something ?

Comment: Does your `obj` hold a string representing JSON or object itself? Try doing a quick watch on obj.

Comment: It is string that has Stringified JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleared the dll from GAC and everything works fine now!

Comment: how did you do that? Could you help please?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with an app that used Json.NET as a private assembly. The issue ocurred only on a specific machine and it turned out that the machine had another version of Json.NET installed in GAC. After removing it from GAC the app started to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The creator of JSON.Net himself addressed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016561/runtimebinderexception-when-using-dynamic-object)

Assuring that it's something minor and the exception is by design.

By the way if you wish to disable these warnings just because they make you uncomfortable.

In Visual Studio click on **Tools** - > **Options** and then select **Debugging** and Check the box that says Enable Just My Code.

More Info [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104874/a-first-chance-exception-of-type-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-runtimebinderex)