# A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred

Tags: c#, exception, dynamic

When using dynamic on Newtonsoft JObjects, I get a lot of `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException` in my debug output. Although the exceptions must be trapped somewhere in Microsoft.CSharp.dll, it makes me vaguely uncomfortable that they are occurring. Is there anything I can do to stop them (other than forgoing dynamic altogether)?

Here is a short test program which outputs one of these exceptions:

```
    using System;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    namespace DynamicTest {
        class Program {
            static void Main(string[] args) {
                JObject j = new JObject();
                j["DocumentName"] = "Name";
                dynamic d = j;
                d.DocumentName = "Changed";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The creator of JSON.Net himself addressed it [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/352)

Assuring that it's something minor and the exception is by design. More information on **RuntimeBinderException** has already been answered here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016561/runtimebinderexception-when-using-dynamic-object)

By the way if you wish to disable these warnings just coz they make you uncomfortable.

In Visual Studio click on **Tools** - > **Options** and then select **Debugging** and Check the box that says **Enable Just My Code**.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll stop worrying about it. I am surprised StackOverflow did not include that previous answer to my question in the list of possible answers. Perhaps I was too specific when I gave the full name of the exception.