# Sudden Death of dynamic JSON - newtonsoft.json.linq.jobject' does not contain a definition for

Tags: xamarin.android, json.net

I am using a simple code to get the values from JSON

```
string JSON = ""; // MY JSON STRING
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(JSON);
Log.Info(TAG, "Access Token " + data.access_token);
```

This was working fine, I don't have any issue debugging but when I run it in production (Android Emulator)
I get the error

> newtonsoft.json.linq.jobject' does not contain a definition for
> "access_token"

My JSON String is the following

```
{
  "access_token": "tIl7bMlOAWJCtdAWKTylZQbo",
  "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

What I want to know is, why this just started happening where it always worked previously for the last 2 years and doesn't show any errors when debugging either?

Comment: I don't know why it would have suddenly stopped working, but given that you know that `data` is a `JObject`, why use `dynamic` at all?  You could do `JObject data = JObject.Parse(JSON);  
string accessToken = (string)data["access_token"];`  This will take the late binding out of the equation.

Comment: I ended up using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTokenModel>(JSON);` but was just curious why it stopped at the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LINQ-to-JSON API (JObject, JToken, etc.) exists to allow working with JSON without needing to know its structure ahead of time. You can deserialize any arbitrary JSON using `JObject.Parse` like the code below. The JObject class can take a string indexer, just like a dictionary.

```
string JSON = @"{'access_token': 'tIl7bMlOAWJCtdAWKTylZQbo', 'token_type': 'bearer'}"; // MY JSON STRING
        var data = JObject.Parse(JSON);
        var s = data["access_token"];
```

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, on the other hand, is mainly intended to be used when you know the structure of the JSON and you want to deserialize into strongly `typed` classes.

```
 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string JSON = @"{
  'access_token': 'tIl7bMlOAWJCtdAWKTylZQbo',
  'token_type': 'bearer'
}"; // MY JSON STRING          


        var jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTokenModel>(JSON);
        var ss = jsondata.access_token;
    }
}

public class MyTokenModel
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I understand that, my question was why the dynamic json stopped working?

Comment: The dynamic json still works well. i uploaded my screenshot.

Comment: You are right, when I use `data["access_token"]` it works but `data.access_token` just stopped working in `dynamic` (no debug errors, it just doesn't work when I run the app)

Comment: @Ali did you find the reason

Comment: @Paddymac I did not look into this issue further for purpose of this project and used the `data["access_token"]` instead. I haven't got a chance to try it again though. Would be interesting to see if it now works again in updated library

Answer (score 0):

The creator of JSON.Net himself addressed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016561/runtimebinderexception-when-using-dynamic-object)

Assuring that it's something minor and the exception is by design.

By the way if you wish to disable these warnings just because they make you uncomfortable.

In Visual Studio click on **Tools** - > **Options** and then select **Debugging** and Check the box that says Enable Just My Code.

More Info [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865136/json-to-dynamic-newtonsoft-json-linq-jobject-does-not-contain-a-definition/71210915#71210915)