# RuntimeBinderException when using dynamic object even though Just My Code checked

Tags: dynamic, xamarin.forms, json.net

I have some very simple code that is throwing a RuntimeBinderException

```
var mockString = "{ Status: \"Aware\" }";
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(mockString);
OutputString = d.Status;
```

I have read a lot of the similar questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016561/runtimebinderexception-when-using-dynamic-object?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the answer given is that it is a first chance exception and I should check "Just My Code' in Tools > Options > Debugging.

I have the code in two solutions. One works and one does not. Both have the "Just My Code" option checked. Both are using the same version of Newtonsoft.Json (8.0.3)

This is VS 2015, Xamarin Forms running on Android.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the debugger break on first chance exceptions for RuntimeBinderException, but when running on Android it was shown as "unhandled" exception in the debugger.

That threw me off for a moment, but after I found out I could continue running without problems I realised it was actually a first chance exception. After turning break on first chance exception of for RuntimeBinderException (since I wasn't interested in those at the time) it worked as expected.

To turn break on first chance exceptions on/off check the menu: Debug -> Windows -> Exception settings